# How to populate checkbox checked property while editing the form in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I'm using CodeIgniter for my project. One of my forms has a checkbox:

```
form_checkbox('will', set_value('will', (isset($set_data->will)) ? $set_data->will : '1'), set_checkbox('will', '1'))
```

It's working fine with form validation and form submit.

I'm using the same form page for 'create' and 'edit' functions, but the checked value is not being repopulated while editing the form. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Please use correct upper case letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found the solution

```
form_checkbox('will', '1', set_checkbox('will', '1', ($set_data->will=='1') ? TRUE : FALSE));
```

Above Code is Working fine with my project